# Can I describe whole Electromagnetism only with electric field $\vec{E}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, electricity, electric-fields

Is it possible to write all Maxwell's equations only in terms of $\vec{E}$ (without $\vec{B}$)? The common formulation of Electromagnetism is governed by the equations below:

**The Lorentz Force:** $$\vec{F} = q( \vec{E} +  \vec{v}  \times  \vec{B}) $$

**Maxwell's equations:**
$$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$
$$\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E} = - \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$$
$$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B} = 0$$
$$c^2 \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{B} = \frac{\vec{j}}{\epsilon _0} + \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}$$

I have heard that $\vec{B}$ is only a mathematical creation of beauty, and can be written as $$\vec{B} = - \frac{\vec{r}}{r} \times \frac{\vec{E}}{c},$$ where $\vec{r}$ is distance vector from the charge to the point at which we want to detect the field. Couldn't the equations be represented as below?

**"Lorentz Force":**
$$\vec{F} = q\vec{E} (1 - \frac{\dot{r}}{r}) - q (\frac{\vec{v}}{c}\cdot\vec{E})\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$$

**"Maxwell's Equations" (only using $\vec{E}$ field):**

$$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$
$$\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\frac{\vec{r}}{r} \times \frac{\vec{E}}{c})$$
$$\vec{\nabla} \times (\frac{\vec{r}}{r} \times \vec{E}) = - \frac{\vec{j}}{\epsilon_0 c}-\frac{1}{c} \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}$$

Perhaps not all the equations above are strictly needed, but the question I have is whether or not I could write all of Maxwell's Equations without $\vec{B}$.

Comment: Personal theories are off-topic here. We deal with mainstream physics only. Remember that magnet you played with as a kid? It doesn’t have an electric field around it when it is at rest.

Comment: @G.Smith But can't you explain all magnetic field phenomenon with Electric Field by using special relativity? (İn this case the magnets) Isn't this the reason why we don't separate Electric Force and Magnetic Force as two fundamental force?

Comment: No. This is a common misunderstanding, usually acquired by watching misleading physics videos. You didn’t learn this in a physics textbook, did you? If so, you misunderstood what it was saying. That fact that electric and magnetic fields mix under Lorentz transformations does not mean that the magnetic field is unnecessary.

Comment: @G.Smith I have seen how to relate electric field and magnetic field using special relativity in some lectures but the rest mostly my interpretation. That's the reason why I asked in the first place. I am not sure.

Comment: The interpretation that you developed is incorrect. For example, a pure magnetic field (i.e., one with no electric field) cannot be transformed away into a pure electric field because $E^2-B^2$ is a Lorentz invariant. You will have to “unlearn” your interpretation in order to properly understand EM.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out but I still have doubts. Can we discuss this at chat, since it seems to getting out of topic

Comment: It was serious question, based on Feynman's lectures. G.Smith You are saying about $E^2 - B^2$ but $\vec{B}=-\frac{\vec{r}}{r} \times \frac{\vec{E}}{c}$. xD

Comment: I mean all what is the most important is the force which will be acting on electron when it is around another charge and lead it along a path, and my equations will give of course right trajectory.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to remind fact that $\vec{B} = - \frac{\vec{r}}{r} \times
>  \frac{\vec{E}}{c}$...

It is valid for a plane wave. You can have for example a charged capacitor in a table. There is an electric field inside it, and also the magnetic field of the Earth. The angle between $\mathbf B$ and $\mathbf E$ can be changed arbitrarily

Comment: Aren’t you confusing $\vec r$ with $\vec k$?

Comment: I mean: the idea that E is normal to B is valid for a EM plane wave.

Comment: Angle between $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{E}$ can be different when it comes from different sources, but then also we can represent $\vec{B}$ as $- \frac{\vec{r}_2}{r_2} \times \frac{\vec{E_2}}{c}$ acting on first charge which generate $\vec{E}_1$.